# trying to make a sidebar with css but cant make it drop line after each button

Tags: css, wordpress

My problem is that 2 buttons (actually text which is a link) are appearing in one line. I want that only one link will be in a line. 
So I'll have 10 lines instead of 8.
By the way, this thing is running on a WordPress theme.

[the sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svL5s.png)

the css code:

```
.menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 55px;
  font-family: "Raleway", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

}
.menu li a {
  font-size: 11px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: #0e1015;
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  max-width: 100%;
  white-space: normal;

}
.menu li a:hover {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
.menu > li {
  margin-right: 32px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  opacity: 1;
}
.menu > li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.menu > li ul {
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 0;
  background: #0e1015;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  top: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transform: translate3d(0, 10px, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 10px, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 10px, 0);
  visibility: hidden;
  margin-top: -1px;
}
.menu > li > ul > li {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 24px;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.menu > li > ul > .dropdown:after {
  color: #0e1015;
  top: 1px;
  right: 24px;
  content: "\f105";
}
.menu > li > ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  height: auto;
  padding: 6px 24px;
}
.menu > li > ul > li > ul {
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
.menu > li:hover > ul {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0px, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0px, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0px, 0);
  visibility: visible;
}
.menu > li > ul > li:hover > ul {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0px, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0px, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0px, 0);
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `float: left;` from your list items.

```
.menu > li {
  margin-right: 32px;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: i did what you said, and now it looks like that. https://s14.postimg.org/s3o7wr1tt/siderbar2.png like there is not enough space for all of the links.

Comment: ok. i deleted the height from the menu class. it's now perfect. what i did is okay?

Comment: Removing the height should be fine.

Comment: @holyubuntu If this has helped you solve your problem please mark this answer as correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove float:left; from li element; they will come automatically one below others